# Do the Night's Dawn Trilogy and the Commonwealth Saga by Peter F. Hamilton share a universe?

Tags: nights-dawn-trilogy, commonwealth-saga

I've read the [*Commonwealth* saga](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11592) and I am considering reading the [*Night's Dawn* trilogy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?3225) by [Peter F. Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_F._Hamilton).

What is the relationship of the universes between the two series? I was under the impression that they were the same universe, but I've read conflicting sources.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are entirely separate; the only real relationship is the author (and some of his ideas).

The Void Trilogy, however, continues in the Commonwealth Saga universe.

Edit: while this is completely subjective, my favourite of the two (or three) was the Night's Dawn trilogy.

Comment: I Agree. If you look at the technology, the two universes take very different approaches to the same issue even if -- with a broad view -- the underlying idea is similar. Eg. TFL is done via wormholes in both, both the usage is very different. Nights Dawn: ships sequential open a wormhole to travel to their next location, Commonwealth: its either fixed infrastructure of continuous wormholes

Comment: I also really liked the Nights Dawn trilogy, but they were the books I started with. The commonwealth series have more books, making it a richer universe.